# Need Help In Creating Excel Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Can someone help me to create formula according to below condition?

[image]

```
Table 1
   Type>> 6-800       6-500      6-100  6-200
Item<<
Book     $10.00        $15.00          $-        ??
Table    $100.00     $-          $200.00     ?? 
Copy     $5.00          $10.00       $30.00      ??  
Pen      $7.00          $8.00          $-        ??  
Pencil   $2.00          $3.00          $-        ?? 
Paper    $1.00          $2.00        $5.00   ?? 

Table 2
Item Type    Price 
6-800 Book   $10.00 
6-800 Table  $100.00 
6-800 Copy   $5.00 
6-800 Pen    $7.00 
6-800 Pencil     $2.00 
6-800 Paper  $1.00 
6-500 Book   $15.00 
6-500 Copy   $10.00 
6-500 Pen    $8.00 
6-500 Pencil     $3.00 
6-500 Paper  $2.00 
6-100 Table  $200.00 
6-100 Copy   $30.00 
6-100 Paper  $5.00 
6-200 Book   $100.00 
6-200 Pencil     $50.00 
6-200 Paper  $10.00
```

I want the formula which will fill the Table 1 with data from Table two.
Conditions are if Type & Item from Table 1 matches with  single column(Item Type) of Table 2 than return value form Price column.

Comment: What have you tried so far and how does it fail to achieve the desired result?

Comment: I am just a starter in excel so don't have much knowledge. Still have tried combining VLOOKUP,ISNUMBER,SEARCH as given below and I don't understand why it didn't show output :(
=VLOOKUP((AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2:A8,G2:G19,6)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2:E2,G2:G19,1)))),G2:H19,2,FALSE)
(I have applied this formula in table two which have only two column Item type and price)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to this:[index match multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767439/lookup-using-index-and-match-with-two-criteria)

To make a long story short try `=index(TABLE2,match(1,($A2=TYPE_Column)*(B$1=Item_Column),0),5)` as an array function. That mean that you have to press `Ctrl +Enter` after entering the formula.

See this link for an explanation of why it works. https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Comment: Thanks @JoeJam I have created formula by combining with yours and I came up with
= IFNA(INDEX(TABLE 2,MATCH(1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($ITEM CELL,ITEM TYPE whole column,6))/1-ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TYPE $CELL,ITEM TYPE whole column,1))/1,0),2),0.00)